# Host an Angular2 application inside a CMS with header and footer manageable from CMS

Tags: angular, content-management-system

Host an Angular2 application inside a CMS with header and footer manageable from CMS[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really the best use/practice. However all that angular does is load your application (via JS/TS) into whatever your the selector is of the component you bootstrap into you main module. So theoretically you could just put in the selector (like `<app-root></app-root>`) inside of your CMSs HTML and include all of your bundled JS.

What I would recommend though is to just create a GET api so that your Angular app can fetch the links from the CMS. (But that's just me)

Comment: @micgaelSolati , Thankyou for your quick reply. But why it is not been considered as the best use/practice. You have any clue?

Comment: Well let&#39;s say that you&#39;re trying to link around the application from the CMS parts of the page. What angular normally does is hijacks the navigation and instead of calling to the server for that route it will render out that route from within itself. If you have a link outside of the angular application you won't have that seamless transition from component to component. Instead it'll call to the server to navigate to that route, and the server would have to respond to the request. So you'll need to have something at that route to return.